# Is there a way to get an input field in the middle of a prompt in python 3?

Tags: python

I am working in python 3 on Pycharm. I currently have code that looks like this:

```py
in_coords = input("Coordinates: ( ")
print( ")" )
```

I want the user input to be in between the two parentheses, so that the program prints "Coordinates: ( )" and the user writes "x, y" in between. Is that even possible? I've got a very basic level of python and I'm not looking to embed this anywhere or have it exist outside of Pycharm.
Thanks!

Comment: Possible. Though, I never tried to do it. This module [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/readline.html#module-readline) works like that. Try going through the documentation.

Comment: it would need to use modules like [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html) - but frankly, for me it is only waste of time. I would display only `Coordinates:` without `( )`